# Add optional argument to new environment template

Tags: environments, optional-arguments, exercises

I'm attempting to create two new environments, one for writing exercises and another for its solutions, with the following characteristics:

- The `Exercise` environment should have:

  1. By default, have no number.
  2. An optional argument in which I customize the exercise number to any number of interest.
  3. All equations listed in this environment should be numbered in the format: `([exercise number].[equation number])`. If the exercise is unnumbered, then the format should be the usual: `([equation number])`.
  4. The equation numbers should reset at each new environment.
- The `Solution` environment should have:

  1. By default, have no number.
  2. An optional argument in which I customize the solution number to any number of interest.
  3. All equations listed in this environment should be numbered in the format: `([exercise number].[equation number])`. The numbering should also follow up with the numbering from the equations listed in the `Exercise` environment.
  4. The equation numbers should reset at each new environment.

At the moment, I'm facing two issues:

1. If I leave both environments unnumbered, then I get the following errors:

> Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{exercise}{}
>
> Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{solution}{}

2. If I leave the exercise environment unnumbered, the equations are numbered: `(0.[equation number])`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\labelsep}{0.3em}

\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]
{\stepcounter{myproblemcnt}\setcounter{myproblemcnt}
{#2}\noindent\hskip\labelsep{\large\bfseries 
#1}\hspace\labelsep{\large\bfseries#2}\par\noindent}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{myproblemcnt}.\arabic{equation}}
\newcounter{myproblemcnt}
\@addtoreset{equation}{myproblemcnt}
\makeatother

\newcounter{myanswercnt}

\newenvironment{solution}[2][Solution]
{\stepcounter{myanswercnt}\setcounter{myanswercnt}
{#2}\noindent\hskip\labelsep{\bfseries 
#1}\hskip\labelsep{\bfseries#2}\par\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}{1}{}
    \textit{This is an exercise.}
    \begin{align}
    i = 2
    \end{align}
\end{exercise}  

\begin{exercise}{}{}
    \textit{This is an exercise.}
    \begin{align}
    i = 2
    \end{align}
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}{1}{}
    This is a first solution.
    \begin{align}
    i = 2 \\
    t = 3
    \end{align}
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}{7}{}
    \textit{This is an exercise.}
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}{1}{}
    This is a first solution.
    \begin{align}
    i = 2 \\
    t = 3
    \end{align}
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}{2}{}
    This is a second solution.
    \begin{align}
        i = 2 \\
        t = 3
    \end{align}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image: MWE-Output]

Comment: #1 (Exercise) is optional, #2 (number) is required.  The protocol is `\begin{Exercise}[optional]{1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you had was pointed out in @JohnKormylo’s comment: You seemed to be confused about LaTeX’s optional argument syntax. According to your requirements, when you want an *unnumbered* exercise, you type something like

```
\begin{exercise} ... \end{exercise}
```

and when you want a *numbered* exercise, you type something like

```
\begin{exercise}[number] ... \end{exercise}
```

There are other issues. For instance, 1. changing `\labelsep` just for your use in the exercise/solution headings is a bad idea; 2. the `<end environment stuff>` to the `\newenvironment` command was missing; 3. the counter `myanswercnt` was never really used; etc.

I’m not entirely sure about the interpretations of your requirements 3 and 4 on `solution`. On the one hand, you want the numbering of the equations in `solution` to follow that in `exercise`. On the other hand, you want the numbering to be reset. I deduce from your requirement 3 that `solution`’s should go *inside* each `exercise`. So here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{myproblemcnt}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{myproblemcnt}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{%
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \stepcounter{myproblemcnt}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    {\large\textbf{Exercise}\par}%
  \else
    \setcounter{myproblemcnt}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{myproblemcnt}.\arabic{equation}}%
    {\large\textbf{Exercise~#1}\par}%
  \fi
}{}

\newenvironment{solution}[1][]{%
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \textbf{Solution}\par
  \else
    \textbf{Solution~#1}\par
  \fi
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[1]
    \textit{This is an exercise.}
    \begin{align}
    i = 2
    \end{align}
\end{exercise}  


\begin{exercise}
    \textit{This is an exercise.}
    \begin{align}
    i = 2
    \end{align}

\begin{solution}[1]
    This is a first solution.
    \begin{align}
    i = 2 \\
    t = 3
    \end{align}
\end{solution}

\end{exercise}


\begin{exercise}[7]
    \textit{This is an exercise.}

\begin{solution}
    This is a first solution, but not numbered.
    \begin{align}
    i = 2 \\
    t = 3
    \end{align}
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}[2]
    This is a second solution.
    \begin{align}
        i = 2 \\
        t = 3
    \end{align}
\end{solution}

\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image: exercises and solutions]